# How do I find the location of a .db file that appears in my Xcode project?

Tags: xcode

I have .db file sitting in resource folder of xcode project.

Where is the location of that file on the disk ?

How I can open that file by using firefox add on for sqllite.

Please let me know some simple trick.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can right-click the file in XCode and select 'Reveal in Finder'

Comment: Great I found the .db file. Now when I go and see the data in the file I do not see them. Where iphone sim hiding the data ? when I do query thru iphone application  I see it but data is  not there in the .db file when I oen thru explorer

Comment: Nevermind after digging some more I found that it get copied to application data.

Answer (score 1):

As requested, a simple trick: right-click (or Control-click if you only have a single button mouse) on the file within Xcode and select "Reveal in Finder".

Answer (score 0):

To see where it is in the project directory - Right click and choose Reveal in Finder.

To see where the data is as used by the simulator - Have a look in the App's bundle.